# Monkey patch eve.methods for additional callbacks

Tags: python, monkeypatching, eve

I am attempting to monkey patch eve methods to provide a callback to do some pre-process and post-process with respectively the request and the reply before they get turned into payloads, e.g.:

```
from eve.methods.patch import patch_internal as __patch_internal
def my_patch(resource, payload=None, **lookup):
    response, last_modified, etag, status = __patch_internal(
                                          resource, payload,
                                          concurrency_check=True,
                                          skip_validation=False, **lookup)
    # call callback depending on resource passing response
    return response, last_modified, etag, status
    import eve.methods
    eve.methods.patch = my_patch
```

The problem I am facing is most of the functions within Eve are imported directly.
I am obliged to fork Eve to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [Event Hooks](http://python-eve.org/features#eventhooks)? They allow you to bind custom callback functions to pre and post events and database operations. Callbacks can alter the original query, the document being stored, or the returned payload.

```
def inject_username_lookup(resource, request, lookup):
    # alter the original query
    lookup["username"] = {'$exists': True}

app = Eve()

app.on_pre_GET += inject_username_lookup
app.run()
```

Since you can hook more than one callback to the same event (they will be executed in sequence), it allows for some pretty nice separation of concerns implementation. [Database events](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks) are powerful too.

Comment: Yes I am already using event hooks, but I would say they are inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, as I was saying, I am already using event hooks.
The example you provided works for adding information to the original request, which is cool.

But I want to add data to the Response (add something which is not in the DB).
It is easy to do in the GET (since the callback provides the response in the callback), but in PATCH, for example, you have no way to inject something, even if it respects the schema.

Just discovered there was a bug in Version 0.5.4... The callback in patch.py takes updates and not updated.

That's why I could not inject stuff in the final reply...

Comment: Ah now I see from where you are coming. It's been fixed recently. Since callbacks solve your issue, you might want to accept the answer so others might benefit from it are, most importantly, are not encouraged to monkey patch when it is actually not needed :)

Comment: Indeed, thank you Nicola for your help. Probably I'll need to have a chat with you one day.